# How to upload dataset without authentication in Palantir foundry

Tags: pyspark, palantir-foundry, foundry-code-repositories

I need to upload a test dataset which is having column names and their respective values to test the functionalities of the production code. How can I upload a dataset without authentication in palantir foundry. Anyone please suggest?

Comment: Why do you want to do it **without** authentication?

Comment: To fetch the data in pytest function using pandas.

Comment: Still not clear to me. Do you want to use the dataset in a pytest function on Foundry, or locally?

Comment: yes, Basically i want to import the dataset in a pytest function on foundry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Short answer:

- You can't upload a dataset without authenticating, that's both a security risk, as well as a data compliance risk, since you don't know who could be uploading that dataset or what it contains.

---

If you want to test your particular code with a prebuilt dataset that you created manually on your computer, you can:

1. create an empty dataset
2. Open it
3. Click add new data
4. Drag your CSV (or other data format) file into the drag and drop box
5. Hit "Next"